# Галочка между иконкой Vue.js и именем файла в WebStorm

Tags: vue.js, webstorm

Что это за галочка между иконкой Vue.js и именем файла?

[image: Галочка между иконкой vue и именем файла]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кажется, у вас имеется закладка для файла `ATList.vue`. Откройте инструмент **Favorites** (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) и проверьте, перечислен ли этот файл в списке **Bookmarks**.

Comment: это SO **на русском**

Answer (score 0):

Вы случайно (специально?) добавили закладку на этот файл. Поставьте на файл курсор и нажмите <kbd>F11</kbd>, чтобы добавить/удалить из этого списка файл. Чтобы посмотреть список всех таких файлов, нажмите <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>F11</kbd>.

Comment: В phpstorm Есть возможность добавить  закладку ко всему файлу и к  заданной строке файла.
В вашем случае закладка присвоена ко всему  файлу.
Поставив курсор на файл в боковом меню и нажав  F11  можно убрать или добавить файл к закладкам.