# На боковой панели, меню файлов IDE phpstorm , есть символ "✔" перед названием файла, что оно означает?

Tags: phpstorm

Использую phpstorm  на боковой панели файлов,  есть символ '✔' перед названием файла, как его убрать и  в чем его предназначение ?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/770353/199253 - наверное подобный вопрос

Comment: Какие попытки вы пробовали предпринять для решения проблемы?

Comment: Правый клик , поисл в документации,  поиск в интернете, потом задал  вопрос

Comment: @Сергей Мишин  да  то что мне нужно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это [bookmark](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2019.3/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#use_bookmarks). Посмотреть на существующие закладки и отредактировать их можно в [Favorites view](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2019.3/managing-your-project-favorites.html)